# Delay timeout of custom calendar message on Mac using Script Editor

Tags: macos, applescript, icalendar

I have the following script that displays a daily message on screen using Mac calender. Problem is it times out after a couple of minutes or so. I would like it to remain on screen for at least 6 hours or until I dimsiss it with the OK button. Please help with the missing code to show the message for longer.

```
set messageList to {"Daily message 1", "Daily message 2", "Daily message 3", "etc..."}

set currentDate to (current date)
set startOfYear to date ("January 1, " & (year of currentDate) as string)
set dayOfYear to (currentDate - startOfYear) div days + 1
set messageIndex to (dayOfYear mod (count of messageList)) + 1
set dailyMessage to item messageIndex of messageList
```

I tried the following :

```
display dialog dailyMessage buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
delay (6 * hours)
```

but all it does is keep the app open on the taskbar but not the message.

Comment: Would you kindly edit your post with the proper formatting of the code please?

Comment: You're probably using the wrong tool for the job. IMO, AppleScript shines when used to control another app for automation or when orchestrating app/s  to achieve a goal. You can probably create the window app with something else, then launch it with AppleScript through your calendar. In that case, the AppleScript achieves its intended use rather than being expected to display a dialog and stay on for hours. To be clear, I have AppleScript apps that stay running for days, visible in the Menu Bar but not as a standalone window/dialog.

Comment: I just had my dinner and the dialog is floating, though I launched as a standalone app. Could it be that the calendar that launched it is causing it to dismiss after sometime?

Comment: @user3579815 Possibly. Which app did you use, if I may ask?

Comment: Another option might be to display a _notification_ - a notification alert will stay on the screen until dismissed.

Comment: I've only used Script Editor to generate an app that displays a dialog. You can probably create a AppleScript app, then launch it by the script that you hooked with the Calendar app.

Comment: Seems like an odd use of the command but try this: `display dialog dailyMessage buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" giving up after 5`. The trailing digit indicates the number of seconds before the dialogue is closed. You could use `6 * 3600` to specify six hours (or just 21600). Look up `display dialog` in the dictionary for `Standard Additions` to see the full usage of the command.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to it to work by adding the following code:

```
displayNotification(dailyMessage, 6 * hours)

on displayNotification(theMessage, duration)
    display dialog theMessage buttons {"Close"} default button "Close" with title "Daily Message" giving up after duration
end displayNotification
```